# 画像のアップロードでエラー: move_uploaded_file() failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php

書籍を使ってPHPを勉強しています
内容はショッピングカートを作ろうというもので、商品画像をアップロードしようというところでつまずいてしまっています。
画像を追加するところで

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(./gazou/aspara_yama.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/product/pro_add_check.php on line 48
```

というエラーになってしまいます
模写したコードは何度も確認したのですが、私の目視では誤っているところは確認できず
アップロードする画像フォルダの共有とアクセス権は読み/書きができるようになっていました
ご回答お願い致します。

```
move_uploaded_file($pro_gazou['tmp_name'],'./gazou/'.$pro_gazou['name']);
print'<img src="./gazou/'.$pro_gazou['name'].'">';
print'<br />';
print'<input type="hidden"name="price" value="'.$pro_price.'">';
```

このようにコードを模写しましたが、画像が表示されず、エラーが出てしまう状況です。

Comment: アップロードする画像フォルダの共有とアクセス権は読み書きできるようになっていたということですが、具体的にどのユーザに対してアクセス権を与えて、読み書きの権限はどのようになっていたか追記いただけますか？

Answer (score 1):

おそらくエラーメッセージの通り、画像アップロード先ディレクトリに書き込み権限が与えられていないものと思います。Linuxなら以下のコマンドを実行すればいいでしょう。

```
chmod 777 [画像保存先ディレクトリのパス]
```

例えば `/var/www/img` に画像を保存する場合は以下のようになります。

```
chmod 777 /var/www/img
```